# Error al modificar una fecha desde Visual Studio a Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

```
//INTANCIAS AL METODO CONECTAR 
        Conexion.Conectar();

        //PREPARAR PROCEDIMIENTO PARA ACTUIALIZAR 
        string actualizar = "UPDATE CRUD_ABOGADOS SET @vID,@vnombre,@vapellidos,@vnacionalidad,@vtipoID,@vtelefono,@vcelular,@vemail,@vfecha_ingreso WHERE ID=@vID";



        //ALMACENAR LOS VALORES EN UNA VARIABLE
        SqlCommand modificar = new SqlCommand(actualizar, Conexion.Conectar());

        modificar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vID", txtid.Text);
        modificar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vnombre", txtnom.Text);
        modificar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vapellidos", txtapell.Text);
        modificar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vnacionalidad", txtnacio.Text);
        modificar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vtipoID", txtipoid.Text);
        modificar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vtelefono", txttelo.Text);
        modificar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vcelular", txtcel.Text);
        modificar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vemail", txtemail.Text);
        modificar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vfecha_ingreso", txtfecha.Text);**aca es donde da el error mostrado en la foto adjunta**
```

> Cuando se le da modificar a la fecha da un error, se esta usando el tipo de datos varchar en Microsoft SQL Server, ya se comprobo los nombres y esta todo igual tanto en el codigo como en el server

[image: error que da al modificar la fecha]

Comment: Aplica debug y mira lo que contiene esa variable.

Comment: No uses `AddWithValue()`. Usa `Add()` y asigna el valor en el tipo de dato correcto.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó correctamente